# Could not select databasename - PHP mySQL Database Querying for XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Got this error guys "Could not select databasename" Im new to PHP and im learning. I'm creating a php script that would generate XML feed from my database. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "my database username";
$dbpass = "my password";
$dbname = "my database name";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("dbname",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select databasename");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM listings";
$q   = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$xml = "<listings>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
  $xml .= "<listings>";
  $xml .= "<listingsdb_title>".$r['listingsdb_title']."</listingsdb_title>";  
  $xml .= "<address>".$r['address']."</address>";
  $xml .= "<class_name>".$r['class_name']."</class_name>";  
  $xml .= "<listingsimages_thumb_file_name>".$r['listingsimages_thumb_file_name']."             </listingsimages_thumb_file_name>";    
  $xml .= "<beds>".$r['beds']."</beds>";   
  $xml .= "<baths>".$r['baths']."</baths>";  
  $xml .= "<sqm>".$r['sqm']."</sqm>";
  $xml .= "<author>".$r['author']."</author>";  
  $xml .= "<full_desc>".$r['full_desc']."</full_desc>";    
  $xml .= "<price>".$r['price']."</price>";  
  $xml .= "</listings>";  
}
$xml .= "</listings>";
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->asXML("listings.xml");
?>
```

Comment: mysql_select_db("dbname",$dbhandle). You were intending to use $dbname variable here...right?

Comment: $selected = mysql_select_db("dbname",$dbhandle) 
in this line are you using the correct name ?i think it should be $dbname in place of "dbname"

Comment: change `"dbname"` to `"$dbname"`. and use PDO/mysqli. `mysql_*` are deprecated.

Comment: Also, it is highly recommended to switch to mysqli_* functions

Comment: thanks for the quick response guys... it works. but my next problem is getting these error "Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]" hahaha crazy me

Comment: @itachi i will consider your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is showing that you didn't select your database..

You have already stored your database name in `$dbname` variable, now just pass it in `mysql_select_db`, like below.

```
$dbname = "my database name";
$selected = mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbhandle) or die("Could not select databasename");
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response... its works but the next error is "Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]" hahaha crazy me, part of learning :-)

Comment: Add `Header('Content-type: text/xml');` line after `$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);`

Answer (score 0):

cange

```
$selected = mysql_select_db("dbname",$dbhandle)  to 
$selected = mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbhandle)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this...

```
$selected = mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select databasename");
```

`"dbname"` **=>**  `$dbname`